# recipe function in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, recipe

Say you have recipes in prolog saved as

```
step(meal name, stepnumber, stepexaplanation, ingredients (list) , utensils).
```

So for every `meal name` you have multiple steps with all the explanations to make the meal. How would you then make a function that calls `getStepText(X,Y,Z).`? So if you ask:

```
?- getStepText('pancakes',2,Y).
```

It will return the text of the second step for the meal pancakes.

Comment: edits must not vandalize the question, nor invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
step('pancakes', 1, 'mix butter and sugar in a bowl', [butter, sugar], [bowl]). 
step('pancakes', 2, 'add eggs', [eggs], []). 
step('pancakes', 3, 'mix flour and bakingpowder', [flour, baking_powder], []). 

getStepText(Dish,Num,Text):-
    step(Dish, Num, Text, _, _).

?- getStepText('pancakes',2,Y). 
Y = 'add eggs' ;
false.
```

If you are using SWI Prolog you can use the inbuild predicate `findall/3` to find all of your steps. Don't forget to sort them.

```
getSteps(X,S):- 
    findall(N,step(X,N,_,_,_),Bag), 
    sort(Bag,S). 

?- getSteps('pancakes',Y). 
Y = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

If you don't want to use `findall/3` you can define a helper predicate `getSteps/3`. This predicate assumes all steps are incremental and start with 1.

```
getSteps(X,S):- 
    getSteps(X,S,1).

getSteps(X, [], N):-
    \+ step(X, N, _, _, _). 
getSteps(X, [N|T], N):-
    step(X, N, _, _, _),
    NN is N+1,
    getSteps(X, T, NN).

?- getSteps('pancakes',Y). 
Y = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

Explanation: you basically run a counter `N` from 1 (set when calling) until you can't find any step with the current number `N`. The first rule tests for the end: if you don't have a step for the current `N` "return" the empty list `[]`.

Otherwise when you find a step with the number `N`, try to find the steplist `T` for the next value `NN` (which is `N+1`) and - once found - put `N` on top of the list `T`.

Comment: Thanks. How would you a function getSteps(X,S). So that when you call getSteps('pancakes',S). It will return S = [1, 2, 3, 4]. For example with the function findall?

Comment: In SWI prolog you can use findall. I'll update my answer once I have running code ;)

Comment: don't forget to accept (and upvote) if this answer satisfies your question.

Comment: under the upvote button should be a gray checkmark. Click it ^^

Comment: So how would you make a predicate to get the ingredients of a recipe. For example for multiple steps you need multiple ingredients. How would you get that back as a list? So when Ingredients('pancakes', X). X would return the list with ingredients?

Comment: I guess you have to open a new question for this. Add a minimal knowledge base and your attempt so far.